# Create IDP SAML responses

Tags: javascript, npm, saml, saml-2.0, idp

I am trying to write some unit test cases for SAML response validation. For this, I need to generate multiple SAML responses (XML). I have required certs & private keys - how can I create/generate a SAML response with it? is there any nodejs library or online tools for that?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of [SAML IDP stacks](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-idp-to-test-now-477761595b60) out there that you can use.

These cater for both SP and IDP Initiated cases.

Comment: Thank you @rbrayb! 
I found an online tool for that - https://8gwifi.org/samlfunctions.jsp

Answer (score 0):

I found an online tool to generate SAML responses - https://8gwifi.org/samlfunctions.jsp